# Как организовать автоматическое тестирование Web-приложения?

Tags: spring-mvc, юнит-тесты, test-automation, java, mockup

Задача автоматически тестировать приложение на сервере, написанное на java со spring MVC. Совершенно новая для меня тема. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как к этому подступиться. Про JUnit в общем немного читала, но как это с серверным приложением работает, никакого понятия. Что мне почитать (желательно на русском)? Суть в том, чтобы тесты имитировали реакцию пользователя, нажатия на кнопки, переход по вкладкам и ввод данных пользователем. Возможно ли это, и как это в принципе делается?

Comment: @Helena2977, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Советую почитать хотя бы [эту статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), в частности про модульное и интеграционное тестирование. Также там ещё есть ручное и автоматизированное тестирование, но им, как правило, занимаются другие люди - QA и QC тестировщики соответственно. От разработчика обычно требуется написание юнит-тестов, в них следует описать крайние случаи методов, например. Это делается для того, что если кто-то делает изменения в коде и впоследствии прогоняет юнит-тесты, то он может найти ошибку в своем свежем коде. Если же функциональность меняется, то следует поменять и юнит-тест. Есть также фреймворки для юнит-тестов javascript.

JUnit - это библиотека для юнит тестов Java кода, так что сервер у вас или нет, абсолютно не имеет значения.

**Обновление**

В моей практике использовали Selenium, да и он вроде самый популярный для автотестов. Учтите, что это фактически освоение новой специализации - тестировщика.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium 
Вроде, там сводится к тому, что вы пишете Java код, который будет кликать на кнопочки, заполнять формочки и т.п. Видел в мониторе у тестировщиков. Больших подробностей не знаю, но можете погуглить в этой области, как минимум на хабре, вроде, есть какие-то статейки.

Comment: Прочитала, но там только общее описание. Как конкретно действовать? Тестировщик у нас уволился, к сожалению, вот и приходится разработчикам самим этим заниматься. А на этом проекте я одна сижу, так что, кроме меня, некому.  
Я вообще подозреваю, что тут нужен не jnit, а что-то совсем другое, чтобы имитировать нажатия кнопок клавиатуры и мышки. Может, надо скрипты писать какие-то? Но не вручную же все. Есть какие-то стандартные средства для этого?

Comment: Что это такое Selenium, это из какой области? Я догадываюсь про специализацию, но ничего сделать пока нельзя. Тестировщика пока нет, а надо быстро сделать.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium 
Вроде там сводится к тому что вы пишете Java код, который будет кликать на кнопочки, заполнять формочки и т.п. Видел в мониторе у тестировщиков. Больших подробностей не знаю, но можете погуглить в этой области, как минимум на хабре вроде есть какие-то статейки.

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать.
А про такой framework Sahi не слышал? Вроде, он похожий, только лучше.

Comment: Нет, не слышал о таком, но беглое гугление подсказывает, что это какой-то аналог, но обучалок/документации на него на русском меньше, судя по всему. А по селениуму, вроде, полно.